# String substitution in a for loop in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Assuming there are lists `xl` and `yl` with the same number of items, and an existing string `s`. I want to susbtitute `xl`'s items with `yl`'s items in `s`. That is, for each `x` in `xl`, I want to call `$(subst x,y,$(s))` where `y` is the corresponding item in `yl`. I tried doing things like:

```
ns := $(shell seq $(words $(xl)))
t := $(foreach i,$(ns),$(subst $(word $(i),$(xl)),$(word $(i),$(yl)),$(s))
```

but this does not work because `foreach` expands `s` [every iteration](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) leading to repetitions in `t`.

What's a good way to get the result I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a recursive function if I understand you correctly:

```
multi-subst = $(if $1,$(call multi-subst,$(wordlist 2,10000,$1),$(wordlist 2,10000,$2),$(subst $(firstword $1),$(firstword $2),$3)),$3)

s = abc dca acacd 
xl = a c
yl = 1 3
s_new := $(call multi-subst,$(xl),$(yl),$(s))
```

It is not possible to replace substrings containing spaces of course. For more functions on strings and list you may want to take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt)

Comment: This seems like a good clever solution except I just get an empty string. Is there something that needs to be escaped?

Comment: There's a missing close paren; the end of the `multi-subst` should be `,$3)),$3)` (note the double parens after the first `$3`.  After that the value `s_new` is replaced.

Comment: @MadScientist oops sorry about that, you are correct. Will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive macro to generate a number sequence and `evaĺ` to make the text substitution, for GNU make 4.2.1:

```make
s   := ABC def GHI bedeft ghi JKL xyz fnops
xl  := abc def ghi nop
yl  := jkl mno pqr (NOP)

# List natural numbers from 1 to length (< 1bn) of list in $1, void if $1 empty
seqn = $(strip $(if $(strip $1),$(call seqn,$(wordlist 2,999999999,$1)) $(words $1),))

ns := $(call seqn,$(patsubst %,x,$(xl)))
t := $(s)
$(foreach i,$(ns),\
    $(eval t:= $$(subst $(word $(i),$(xl)),$(word $(i),$(yl)),$$(t))))

.PHONY: all
all : ; $(foreach v,ns s t,$(info $(v): [$($(v))]))
```

Output from `make --silent`:

```
ns: [1 2 3 4]
s: [ABC def GHI bedeft ghi JKL xyz fnops]
t: [ABC mno GHI bemnot pqr JKL xyz f(NOP)s]
```

**EDIT**

- `foreach` should loop on indices of replacement list, not target string
- call `seqn` macro with `$(patsubst %,x,list)` for speed
- only `$(subst …)` and `$(t)` need escaping with `$$` in `eval` stmt

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to operate on each word of `s` separately, I think.

Something like:

```
t := $(foreach w,$(s),$(foreach i,$(ns),$(subst $(word $i,$(xl)),$(word $i,$(yl)),$w)))
```

Comment: This does not work. It's got repetitions due to the foreach expansion quirk.

Comment: I see.  It's not the case that `s` is expanded multiple times.  The problem is that each time through the loop each word is replaced and then appended to the results of the previous time through the loop.  For questions like this it would be very helpful if you provided an example makefile with your solution and showed the results you wanted to get.